# How to match two lists of discrete values with different bin sizes?

Tags: python, pandas, encoding, timestamp, binning

I've got two DataFrames including 2 columns (Timestamp and Consumption) both in a 24 hour period. The data in the first DataFrame is recorded every 8 seconds and the data in the second DataFrame is recorded every 6 seconds. The dataset is about 2 different devices in a house for the same day. Now I want to match these two DataFrames to be able to subtract one from the other. In fact, I want to convert the 8second interval DataFrame to a 6second interval DataFrame.

Example (arbitrary consumption values):

```
DataFrame A: timestamp  consumption
             00:00:00   125
             00:00:08   123
             00:00:16   150
             00:00:24   142
             00:00:32   130

DataFrame B: timestamp  consumption
             00:00:00   235
             00:00:06   222
             00:00:12   341
             00:00:18   321
             00:00:24   302
             00:00:30   289
```

notice that sometimes the timestamps are not accurate and the interval sometimes might be 7 seconds instead of 8 or 6 due to noise probably.

**UPDATE:** I have the consumption of the DataFrame A, at 00:00:00 and 00:00:08 (125 and 123 respectively) and I want to estimate the value at 00:00:06

Comment: Could you give us an example of the expected output?

Comment: sure. Let's look at A. We have 125 at 00:00:00 and 123 at 00:00:08. I want a way to estimate the value at 00:00:06 in the A. So I'll be able to compare it with the peer record in the B.

Comment: How do you want to estimate the consumption? Let's say it consumes a at time A and b at time B. You want to estimate the consumption c at time C, where A<C<B. How would you manually estimate c? Something like c = (b(C-A)+a(B-C)) / (B-A)?? That it, does the consumption increase/decrease linearly between A and B?

Comment: @Riccardo Bucco: that's exactly what I'm asking here dude :D
For example, when you plot data points using a line graph while you move your cursor to somewhere between two data points (on the line) it shows you an (x,y) value which represents the point your cursor is on. The lines between two datapoints somehow estimate the values between two data points.

Comment: So does my comment answer your question? If you just want to approximate the consumption with a linear function between two points then you can use the formula I provided in my previouus comment

Comment: @Riccardo Bucco: It worked. Thanks a lot man 